# Virtualbox port forwarding not working

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

Currently I'm running a setup where I have a Linux Host (Ubuntu 18.04.3 if that matters) with virtualbox running a Windows 10 Guest. I have configured the guest to use 2 network interfaces. One NAT and another one bridged.

Both of these interfaces work correctly as the guest machine can reach it's host on both, but the other way around seems to be impossible. I have set the port forwarding for TCP port 8080 on the guest to port 12345 on the host. I have set this on the NAT interface. Then I rebooted both host and guest.

I then made sure I was running a java server on the guest on port 8080 (nothing else running) which I was able to reach perfectly from the guest itself, but still unable from host. I have tried the following 3 url's to no avail:

1. http://{guest ip}:8080
2. http://{localhost}:8080
3. http://{localhost}:12345

I firmly believe number 3 should work with the port forwarding, however I get a never-ending loop of not showing up.
Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I found it. Apparently, there are multiple firewall rules for Windows that might get in the way. Turning off firewalling immediately fixed the issue. Now I just have to figure out what rules will work so I can turn the firewall back on.

This issue is resolved for now.